# postgres sorting based on multiple date value's

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by

I have one project table with projects with the columns `start_at` (date) `end_at`(date) pauzed_at (date) etc.
And I want to order the projects, based on date values.

Sorting should be;

```
- STARTED projects
- PAUZED projects
- IDLE projects 
- ENDED projects
```

project is started when the date is between `start_at` & `end_at`.

project is idle when start_at date is not reached.

project is ended when end_at date is reached.

project is paused when paused_at is set etc etc.

How can I sort this table, based on the state of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The states can be represented by a `case` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   projects
ORDER BY CASE WHEN paused_at IS NOT NULL THEN 2 -- paused
              WHEN ended_at() < NOW() THEN 4 -- ended
              WHEN started_at() > NOW() THEN 3 -- idle
              ELSE 1 -- started
         END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

`false` orders before `true`:

```
order by
    now() >= start_at and now() < end_at desc,
    paused_at is null,
    now() < start_at desc,
    now() >= end_at desc
```

A `case` expression is an optimization barrier to the planner.